# Search a list of conditions

Tags: algorithms, search

If I have a list of conditions:

```
and(a,or(b,c))
not(b)
or(a,c)
and(a,d)
or(or(or(a,b),c),d)
```

and I'm given values for these conditions, let's say, `a=true, b=false, c=false, d=true`, what is a good algorithm to find the true ones in less than `O(log n)`? I'm trying to avoid testing all conditions.

A good context for this problem would be wireshark trying to check for filters for every possible part of the currently parsed packet

Comment: If there is one true between multiple OR, you can short circuit as true. If there is one false between multiple AND, you can short circuit as false. I think the worst case is O(n), since you could have a lot of AND and a lot of true.